# Ubuntu 18.04 chroot locale can't set

Tags: 18.04, locale, chroot

I am installing a Ubuntu 18.04 chroot on a Debian 8 system, using `ubuntu-base-18.04.3-base-i386.tar.gz` as the base (found from the Ubuntu website).

I mount the `/sys` and `/proc` directories into the chroot and recursively mount `/dev` into the chroot, and copy the resolve.conf from the hose to the chroot.

When I install nano into the chroot, I get errors about the locale not being set:

```
$ apt-get -qq install --no-install-recommends nano
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_DK.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package nano.
```

The `locales` command shows:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_DK.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_DK.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

$ locale -a
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
```

When I try to use the typical locale set commands:

```
$ locale-gen
bash: locale-gen: command not found

$ localectl
bash: localectl: command not found

$ update-locale
bash: update-locale: command not found

$ dpkg-reconfigure locales
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_DK.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (Can't locate Term/ReadLine.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Term::ReadLine module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl/5.26.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl/5.26 /usr/share/perl/5.26 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl-base) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Readline.pm line 7.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
dpkg-query: package 'locales' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: locales is not installed
```

The `/etc/environment` file shows

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Other Files:

`/etc/default/locale`

```
cat: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory
```

`~/.profile`

```
# ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.

if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi

mesg n || true
```

`~/.bashrc`

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#fi
```

`/usr/lib/locale`

```
$ ls /usr/lib/locale
C.UTF-8
$ ls /usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8                
LC_ADDRESS  LC_COLLATE  LC_CTYPE  LC_IDENTIFICATION  LC_MEASUREMENT  LC_MESSAGES  LC_MONETARY  LC_NAME  LC_NUMERIC  LC_PAPER  LC_TELEPHONE  LC_TIME
$ ls /usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/
SYS_LC_MESSAGES
```

Copying the `/usr/lib/locale` from the host to the chroot also did not work.

**I would like a non-interactive way to solve this problem that takes up as little space as possible, as I am scripting the creation of this chroot.**

**What commands or packages do I need to install to be able to solve this in a shell script?**

**Are there packages I can install, run to setup locale and then uninstall to save space?**

Comment: The simplest way to fix it seems to be to generate the `en_DK.UTF-8` locale: `sudo locale-gen en_DK.UTF-8`

Comment: How do I install local-gen? What package is it apart of?

Comment: `locales` (which there probably are many other reasons to install too)

Comment: Still getting errors after installing `locales` & running `locale-gen en_US.UTF-8`: Running `locale -a` gives `locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory, locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory, locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory` and running `update-locale --help` shows `perl: warning: Setting locale failed. perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings: LANGUAGE = (unset), LC_ALL = (unset), LANG = "en_DK.UTF-8" are supported and installed on your system.`

Comment: It was `locale-gen en_DK.UTF-8` I suggested.